# How can I obtain the data from a tensorflow Variable in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, variables

I will love to know how I could obtain the data from a tensorflow **Variabe** object using the C++ API. For example, with a pure Tensor object with reference obj for example, doing `obj->flat<Type>().data()` returns all the tensor data. Is there a similar way to extract data from a Variable object ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got a hint on how to do it. I run the variable in a session and send the results to an output Tensor vector. I then extract the values from the corresponding Tensor object as described in the question.

```
std::vector<Output> outputs;
auto my_var = Variable (...);
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({my_var},&outputs));
print(output[0]);
```